# How to compute the difference between 2 string columns in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have 2 columns in the same dataframe as below:

```
A               B
abcdef(as3456)    as3456
pqrst(dh6546)     dh6546
```

I need to create another column C such as below:

```
  C
 abcdef
 pqrst
```

I have been able to create column B from A however, my purpose is not fully served yet. Can someone please help me getting Column C as I mentioned  from Column A and B. I tried doing != opertor and "~loc". HOwever, that does not seem to work in this case.(may be because its a string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For difference between columns per rows use `replace` with `strip`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['abcdef(as3456)', 'pqrst(dh6546)', 'abcdef(dh6546)'], 
                   'B': ['as3456', 'dh6546', 'as3456']})

print (df)
                A       B
0  abcdef(as3456)  as3456
1   pqrst(dh6546)  dh6546
2  abcdef(dh6546)  as3456#df.B not matched per rows, but matched abcdef by first value of df.B

#replace values from df.B per rows
df['C'] = [i.replace(j, '').strip('()') for i, j in zip(df.A, df.B)]

#replace all values from df.bvalues
pat = '|'.join([r'\({}\)'.format(i) for i in df.B])
df['D'] = df.A.str.replace(pat, '')
print (df)
                A       B              C       D
0  abcdef(as3456)  as3456         abcdef  abcdef
1   pqrst(dh6546)  dh6546          pqrst   pqrst
2  abcdef(dh6546)  as3456  abcdef(dh6546  abcdef
```

Comment: Thanks a lot... :)

Comment: @sayan_sen - There was added a new row of data for show difference betwen, is my solution what need?

Answer (score 0):

```
df['C']=df.A.replace(regex=r'\(.*$', value='')

df
                A       B       C
0  abcdef(as3456)  as3456  abcdef
1   pqrst(dh6546)  dh6546   pqrst
```

or you can do:

```
df['C']=df.A.replace(regex=r'\('+ df.B +r'\)',value="")
              A       B       C
0  abcdef(as3456)  as3456  abcdef
1   pqrst(dh6546)  dh6546   pqrst
```